# Saving continuously generated simulation data with Python3

Tags: python, numpy, format, save, simulation

So my question is how I should save a large amount of simulation data to a file using Python (or update new data rows to the existing file).

Lets say I have `NN=1000` particles, and I want to save the position and velocity data of each particle (x y z, vx vy vz). The data is in format `[x1,y1,z1,vx1,vy1,vz1, x2,y2,z2,vx2,vy2,vz2, ...]` and so on.

Simulation is working well, but I believe the methods I use for saving and keeping these information saved is not really optimal for me.

Pseudo code similar to my code

```
T_max = 1000   # for example
dt = 0.1       # time step
T  = 0         # current time
iterations = int(T_max/dt)  # number of iterations we are doing
NN = 1000      # Number of particles

ZZ = np.zeros( (iterations, 2+NN*6  ) )  # Here I generate whole data matrix at the beginning. 
# ^ might not be the best idea as the system needs to keep everything in memory for the whole time
#   So I guess saving could be done in chunks?

ZZ[0][0], ZZ[0][1] = T , dt 
# ZZ[0][2:]  = initialize_system(NN=NN) # so lets initialize the system. 
# However, for this post I do this differently due to simplicity. See below
ZZ[0][2:] = np.random.uniform(-100,100,NN*6)

i = 0
while i < iteration:
     T += dt    
     Z[i+1][0], Z[i+1][1] = T, dt
     #Z[i+1][2:]  = rk4(EOM_function, posvel=Z[i][2:]) 
     # ^ Using this I would calculate new positions based on previous ones.
     Z[i+1][2:]   = np.random.uniform(-100,100,NN*6) #This is just for example here.
     
     i += 1

# Now the simulation data is basically done, so one would need to save

# This one feels slow, as it takes 181s to save and is size of 1046246KB
np.savetxt('test1.txt', ZZ)

#other method with a bit less accuracy as I don't need to have all decimals saved
np.savetxt('test2.txt', ZZ, fmt='%1.6f') # Takes 125s and size is 426698KB

# Both of the above are kinda slow so I also tried to save to npy format
np.save('test.npy', ZZ) # It took 8.9s and size 164118KB
```

so this `np.save()` method seems to be fast, but I read somewhere that I can not append data to it. So this would not work if I keep saving the data in parts while calculating new positions.

So back to my question. How should/could I save the data efficiently (fast and memory friendly). I keep having some memory issues when `NN` and `T_max` gets larger because with this method I keep this whole `ZZ` all the time in memory.

So I guess I should calculate `ZZ` in parts, i.e. `iterations/10` parts but then I should append this data to an existing file, and tests I have made felt slow. Any suggestions?

EDIT: feel free to ask more specifying questions as I feel like I forgot to explain something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That highly depends on what you intend to use the output for. If it's stored for further calculations, `.npy` or some other binary format is always the way to go as it is faster, takes less space, and doesn't lose precision between loads and saves, instead of serializing it into a human readable format. If you need it to be readable, you might as well just output row by row to a csv file or something.

If you want to do it with binary, h5py allows you to extend a dataset after saving and append more stuff to it.

```py
import numpy as np
import h5py

T_max = 10**4   # for example
dt = 0.1       # time step
T  = 0         # current time
iterations = int(T_max/dt)  # number of iterations we are doing
NN = 1000      # Number of particles
chunk_size = 10**3

ZZ = np.zeros( (chunk_size, 2+NN*6  ) )
ZZ[0][0], ZZ[0][1] = T , dt
# ZZ[0][2:]  = initialize_system(NN=NN) # so lets initialize the system.
# However, for this post I do this differently due to simplicity. See below
ZZ[0][2:] = np.random.uniform(-100,100,NN*6)
with h5py.File("test.h5", "a") as f:
    dset = f.create_dataset('ZZ', (0,2+NN*6), maxshape=(None,2+NN*6), dtype='float64', chunks=(chunk_size,2+NN+6))

    for chunk in range(0, iterations, chunk_size):
        for i in range(0, chunk_size - 1):
            T += dt
            ZZ[i + 1][0], ZZ[i + 1][1] = T, dt
            #Z[i+1][2:]  = rk4(EOM_function, posvel=Z[i][2:])
            # ^ Using this I would calculate new positions based on previous ones.
            ZZ[i + 1][2:]   = np.random.uniform(-100,100,NN*6) #This is just for example here.

        # Expand the file here to allow for more data.
        dset.resize(dset.shape[0] + chunk_size, axis=0)
        dset[chunk: chunk + chunk_size ] = ZZ

        # update and initialize next chunk. the next chunk's first row should be the last row of the previous chunk + iteration
        T += dt
        ZZ[0][0], ZZ[0][1] = T, dt
        #Z[0][2:]  = rk4(EOM_function, posvel=Z[-1][2:])
        # ^ Using this I would calculate new positions based on previous ones.
        ZZ[0][2:]   = np.random.uniform(-100,100,NN*6) #This is just for example here.

        print(dset.shape)
```

This takes 70 seconds on the save step on my computer, generating a 45GB file, for a dataset that is 100 times your original code.

The above code is more general in case you are streaming your data and don't know your final size. If you know it from the start, you can replace the initial create_dataset with
`dset = f.create_dataset('ZZ', (iterations,2+NN*6), dtype='float64')`
and remove the `dset.resize(dset.shape[0] + chunk_size, axis=0)`

You'll probably also want to read it back in chunks afterwards for other processing, in which case you can follow the docs here: https://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data

Comment: I had now time to check this, and indeed this seems like method suitable for my case. However, when I run your code I noticed that after the first 'chunck' all it saves are zeros. This is how I read the file ``f = h5py.File("test7.h5", "r")`` , and then get the data ``ZZ2 = f['ZZ']`` .  The shape is correct , ``print(f'{ZZ2.shape = }')`` = (10000, 6002) but i.e. when I take ``ZZ2[900:1200,0]`` the time T works fine till the first chunk. So in my test it works fine well for 99.8 and then after that everything is zeros.  Also second row is full of zeros too. I try to find solution on my own too.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the params were floats, I gave you a h5 that only stores integer version. replaced the i8 with float64, which is why the 2nd column was 0. Also made an error on the indexing when transcribing over, which is why after chunk 1 it wasn't updating. Just updated it, it should work now.

Comment: Now it works. I noticed that integer / float mistake which was not too bad, but I got confused about the indexing. Now it indeed makes sense !

Answer (score 0):

**Okay so I'm continuing my question / providing possible answer to it based on the answer of EricChen1248. EDIT: Answer provided by EricChen1248 works now and is way better than this my code part. See his code**

I do not yet still understand completely how this `f.create_dataset ()` truly works (i.e. when does it write data to file in the loop etc).

Using the code provided by Eric, it created and saved the data files fastly, but when I read the file as follows

```
hf = h5py.File('temp/test.h5', 'r')
ZZ = np.array(hf['ZZ'])
hf.close()
```

and plotted the first column (time `T` column, which should increase by timestep `dt` after each iteration) I get the following figure
`plt.plot(ZZ[:,0])`
[time T column plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68OvR.png)
and as can be seen, it grows to a time of 100, and then goes to zero. This happens after the first 'chunk_size' has been passed. I started to read docs provided by Eric, and using his code as reference I managed to write something like this

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

T_max = 10**4
dt = 0.1
T = 0
NN = 1000
iterations = int(T_max/dt)
chunk_size = 10**3

with h5py.File('temp/data12.h5', 'a') as hf:
    dset = hf.create_dataset("ZZ", (chunk_size, 2+NN*6),maxshape=(None,2+NN*6) ,chunks=(chunk_size, 2+NN*6), dtype='f8' )
    # ^ first I create data set equals to one chunk_size

    # Here I initialize the system. Columns ; 0=T , 1=dt, 2=arbitrary data point, 3=sin(column2)
    # all the rest columns are random numbers just to fill some numbers in

    dset[0,0], dset[0,1] = T, dt 
    #dset[0,2:] = np.random.uniform(0,1,NN*6)
    dset[0,2] = 1
    dset[0,3] = np.sin(dset[0,2])
    dset[0,4:] = np.random.uniform(0,1,NN*6 -2)
    print('starts')
    
    # Main difference down there is that I use dataset (dset) 
    # as a data matrix to be filled instead of matrix ZZ as in my question. 

    i = 0
    #for j, s in enumerate(dset.iter_chunks()):
    for j, s in enumerate(range(0, iterations, chunk_size )):
        print(j, s)
        while i < iterations and i < chunk_size*(j+1) -1:
        #for i in range(chunk_size*j, chunk_size*(j+1)-1):
            T += dt
            dset[i+1,0], dset[i+1,1] = T, dt
            #dset[i+1,2:]  = np.sin(dset[i,2:]+dt)
            dset[i+1,2] = dset[i,2] + dt
            dset[i+1,3] = np.sin(dset[i,2]+dt)
            dset[i+1,4:] = dset[i,4:] + np.random.uniform(-1,1,NN*6-2)
            i+=1
            
        print(dset.shape)
        dset.resize(dset.shape[0] + chunk_size, axis=0)
```

This code runs in 1min 50s , and saves a file of size  4.47GB so I am happy with the speed, and what I'm really happy is that it do not use so much memory while iterating (I used to get into problem with huge RAM usage).

When I read the data file provided by my code (similarly as above) I get following image for time [Time T column plotted, my code version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7QxQ.png) and it grows nicely to `T=10e4` as should be. It still generated one more `chunk_size block` to the end of dataset which is full of zeros. That I need to get rid of. One more proof that the code works and saves data without weird problems is this sinusoidal plot `plt.plot(ZZ[500:1500,0] , ZZ[500:1500,3])`. [Sinusoidal image proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F12nP.png) Note that the plot is limited for `T ~ [50,150]` so one could still see something there (if plotted the whole thing, one could not see lines well).

I believe this is not the best way to write this code, but it is the way I got this working. So if someone sees improvements, please let me know. Also, I am curious to know why the code provided by Eric did not work, at least for me.

EDIT : fixed typos

Comment: Haha, looks like you mostly worked it out while I was editting my response. You have a extra blank chunk because are calling resize at the end of your loop while also initializing a chunk. Either set an if condition to not resize on last chunk, or move to the front of the loop without an initial chunk size.

Comment: For your question on when it's written to file. create_dataset is basically creating a container that is backed by a file instead of stored in memory. So at a high level it is writing to file when ever you write to dset. At a technical level there is likely some buffering somewhere that is flushed to file to improve performance, which is why it is important to wrap it in a `with` block

Comment: oh I see now that extra blank chunk problem too. Thanks for pointing it out as well as explaining how ``create_dataset`` behaves !